# Nested views : binding events with proper ui

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I have app where one type of view is nested in same type. Something like this `http://take.ms/ylAeq`

How can I catch event on view button and fired event on proper view?

I have situation when I have **~10**  fired events becuase backbone binds event to all inner buttons, not only button of proper view.

I have one idea - I make in template `id="node_body_<%= id %>"`  so each button id based on it's view's model id; but how can I pass it to events object? events :`{ "click #node_body_" + id : 'method' }` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is event bubbling. The events on your inner view's bubble upto the `el` of it's parent view's, which is listening for events on same selector, in turn triggering it's handler.

This can be fixed by stopping the propagation of event in the respective view's handler:

```js
Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
    'click .thing': 'do_thing'
  },
  do_thing: function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation(); // prevents event reaching parent view
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank u for ur answer but i have one type view nested each other. So, if i will use that do_thing function i will break event triggering on each view (parent and child)

Comment: @PavelPoberezhnyi I understand that you have same view's nested. So each view has it's own `do_thing` method. when an event triggers in a view, it'll invoke it's `do_thing` method, and none of the other view's will invoke their  `do_thing`. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Thank u, now i understand ur idea. I'll try it and give u feedback

Comment: Ur method works really good. Thank u very much. Really nice solution. I found that my understanding of event.stopPropagation(); is really poor.

Answer (score 0):

Most properties of Backbone views can be functions instead of literal values. For example, these two things have the same result:

```
Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click .thing': 'do_thing'
    },
    do_thing: function() { ... }
});
```

and

```
Backbone.View.extend({
    events: function() {
        return {
            'click .thing': 'do_thing'
        };
    },
    do_thing: function() { ... }
});
```

So if your `events` depend on properties of the view, then you'd want to use a function instead of an object literal:

```
events: function() {
    var events     = { };
    var event_spec = 'click #nody_body' + this.id;
    events[event_spec] = 'method';
    return events;
}
```

That assumes that `id` is the property of the view that you're using in your template.

Comment: Briliant. Thank u for ur answer. I will try this solution